# Arduino (Or Raspberry Pi) As HID Device

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi

I have an Arduino Uno and A Raspberry Pi B+. I was wandering how I could use either as a Programbel HID Device (EX: https://srlabs.de/badusb/). The Reason I ask under the arduino section is I want to preferably use it. If not I can use either.

Comment: The Arduino question has already been asked and answered.  As for the pi, it is theoretically possible with a model A or zero to operate the USB as a device rather than host, though I'm not sure anyone has ever done so.  But with models such as the B+ having multiple USB connectors, an onboard USB hub gets in the way of operating in device mode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Uno cannot be used as a HID device through the on board USB. You might be able to use the [V-USB Library](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) to be a HID device using the digital IO pins. See [this tutorial](http://blog.petrockblock.com/2012/05/19/usb-keyboard-with-arduino-and-v-usb-library-an-example/).

There are several arduino compatible boards that do can act as a HID device natively. Most boards built around the ATMega32u4 can be a HID device.  For example the [Arduino Micro](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMicro)

See [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32197/can-the-pi-emulate-an-hid-device-with-via-usb) about the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I would share our experience with V-USB. For educational purposes, we had the opportunity to use like 15+ Arduinos with V-USB (Adafruit Trinket). At the moment, only two of them works well. There are various issues with newer motherboards, Windows 10, and mystic enumeration problems. I strongly recommend going for 32u4, such as Arduuno Leonardo or Arduino Micro (or any similar product with 32u4)

Comment: This answer is not correct in saying that it is not possible with the stock hardware.  The Uno's USB interface is provided by a reprogrammable ATmega8u2 or 16u2, and there are writeups online of how to program that to be an HID device.  Granted, there is the subsequent difficulty of the USB-serial channel not then being available to program the Arduino, though a dual-mode firmware is conceivably possible, if perhaps challenging to use with OSX hosts.

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/484/arduino-as-usb-hid